# Spring RESTFul и View для него

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

У меня есть RESTful контроллер для приложения, позволяющее просматривать записи из БД по их id.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/logs")
public class AppAdminController {

    @Autowired
    RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry registry;

    @Autowired
    RestLogRepository restLogRepository;

    @Autowired
    RestLogRepositoryCustomImpl restLogRepositoryCustom;

    final ModelMapper modelMapper;

    public AppAdminController(ModelMapper modelMapper) {
        this.modelMapper = modelMapper;
    }


    @ApiOperation("Поиск body лога по его id")
    @GetMapping("/body/{id}")
    public String readBodyById(
        @PathVariable(value = "id", required = true) Long logId
    ) {
        return GzipUtils.unzip(restLogRepository.findByLogId(logId)
            .orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException("Element not found")).getBody());
    }

    @ApiOperation("Поиск лога по его id")
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public RestLogDto readById(
        @ApiParam("id лога")
        @PathVariable(value = "id", required = true) Long logId) {
        return DtoConverter.convert(
            restLogRepository.findByLogId(logId).orElseThrow(() -> new NoSuchElementException("Element not found")),
            modelMapper);
    }
}
```

Значения возвращаются в виде класса и, соответственно, преобразуются в JSON.

```
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)    
public class RestLogDto {
    Long id;
    Long responseId;
    String javaLogId;
    Date createdOn;
    Date responseCreatedOn;
    String status;
    String responseStatus;
    String message;
    String responseMessage;
    String responseDuration;
    String body;
}
```

**Вопросы:** Каким образом нужно реализовать View для этого приложения? Нужно ли писать еще один (уже MVC) контроллер? 
Насколько я понял, сама суть RestController в том, чтобы возвращать не View, а данные. Будет ли в таком случае само желание добавить сюда View ошибочным?

В интернете супер-много информации и статей, которые только сильнее путают и вгоняют в ужас меня как лоулевельного джуна, поэтому надеюсь на вас. Заранее спасибо

Comment: Зачем вам нужна модель?

Comment: В чем отличия `CustomRestRepo` от обычного `RestRepo`?

Comment: `CustomRestRepo` реализует запрос, которого я не смог добиться, используя магические методы спринга. Там нативный SQL запрос.
В простом `RestRepo` лежат запросы с JPA спецификацией. Здесь представлен укороченный вариант кода, часть где это используется - я порезал. Меня интересует конкретно вопрос с View для подобных случаев. Хотя, как я понял, RESTful в целом подразумевает то, что будет возвращатся json, а не view (и фронт надо писать отдельно), так что вопрос, в целом, можно закрывать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Реализовывать View для RESTfull сервиса - ошибка. View(как и Model) нужно только для MVC-приложения.

REST сервис должен возвращать данные, предпочтительно JSON. В большинстве случаев вы можете возвращать сам объект(который ищите по id), а Spring автоконвертирует его в JSON.

Фронт вам надо писать отдельно, на JS. В ванильном JS вы можете просто отправлять HTTP запросы на свой рест, и получать ответы используя [`XHR`](https://learn.javascript.ru/xmlhttprequest). Но это сложный способ, гораздо легче использовать какой нибудь фреимворк, например Angular или Vue.

Также вы можете не писать второй `CustomRepository`, а использовать аннотацию [`@Query`](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-query) на методе в обычном `Repository`.